# unable to access webService with SoapClient authentication function

Tags: php, web-services, authentication, soap

I have a problem when I want to make an Authentication to a WebService by a function name "startSession"

I make the SoapClient :

```
$client = new SoapClient("Authentication.xml",array('trace'=>1));
```

And the call to the function :

```
$login = "login";
$mdp = "pass";
$params = new SoapParam(array("login"=>$login,"password"=>$mdp),"parameters");


try {
        var_dump($client->startSession($params));
} catch (Exception $e) {
        echo($client->__getLastResponse());
        echo PHP_EOL;
        echo($client->__getLastRequest());

}
```

But the only thing I obtain in web is :

> loginmdp

That corresponds to the lastRequest sent

So how can I Authenticate to my WebService ?

Thank you in advance